# How to find and delete a file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Hi i was making a software which deletes a particular file. For example in the location C:\Program Files\Unused\example.exe.
I haven't type any code because i am still trying to figure it out. Sorry about that ! Please help me !

Comment: Start here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io(v=vs.110).aspx and see how you get along.

Comment: The answer to that is actually [here.](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets8p8.html) You just have to search for *how to delete a file in vb.net*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very very simple way to delete a file in VB.Net

```
Dim FileToDelete As String
FileToDelete = "C:\Program Files\Unused\example.exe"
If System.IO.File.Exists( FileToDelete ) = True Then
  System.IO.File.Delete( FileToDelete )
  MsgBox("File Deleted")
End If
```

Comment: Thanks ! it's working ! I am very new to VB.NET and you helped me a lot !

Comment: No problem ;) We are here for help people.